# Why are all my questions subjective?

Tags: discussion, quality-filter

Each question I write get the "Your question seem to be subjective"-warning.

How does this algorithm work? Not very well I think. I don´t think my questions have been subjective and so far no one have been closed.

My three latest questions:

[How do you do client side routing when saving via methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842892/how-do-you-do-client-side-routing-when-saving-via-methods)

[How do you set a tutorial project to a specific git commit state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36908798/how-do-you-set-a-tutorial-project-to-a-specific-git-commit-state)

[What am I doing wrong when manipulating data in Meteor/MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682580/what-am-i-doing-wrong-when-manipulating-data-in-meteor-mongodb)

Comment: It works off a simple word match.  Using "best" in your question title is the best way to trigger it afaik.  Asking for the "best way" is always subjective.  What other words are checked for is not documented, best to assume they are subjective words.  The ones you came up with next look fine, maybe it works well :)

Comment: I have uppdated with links to my three latest questions.

Comment: Ok @HansPassant. I get your point. Though I think that can be a very interesting question and don´t really get why they are not allowed.

So, is it ok to instead of asking "Which is the best way to...?" ask "Can you show me one (good) way to...?"

Comment: Just don't pad your question title with useless verbiage.  Nobody ever looks for the worst way.  It is already assumed by anybody that could answer your question that they are supposed to "show you" and give your a "good way" so there is no need whatsoever to demand it.

Comment: Your first question contains "So whats the most elegant solution?" Elegance is subjective. I cannot say whether that's what the filter picked up on but if it did, then the warning was warranted.

Comment: Just convert "best" according to what you mean: If you mean shortest code write simplest, if you mean fastest execution write fastest, ...

Comment: Thats true @Louis, but the warning fire of when you complete the subject.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for tips regarding how to formulate questions. Will keep it in mind.

Comment: You could also try "How do I ___?" instead of "How do you ___?"